Problema de tipos redux-thunk - Typescript
Estoy experimentando un error de tipos en mi store de redux cuando intento configurar redux-thunk en el mismo:
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import currentComponentReducer from './features/currentComponentSlice';
import userSliceReducer from "./features/userSlice";
import filterSliceReducer from "./features/filterSlice";
import popularGiftsSliceReducer from "./features/popularGiftsSlice";
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk';

const reducers = combineReducers({
    currentComponentReducer,
    userSliceReducer,
    filterSliceReducer,
    popularGiftsSliceReducer
});

const persisteConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['currentComponentReducer', 'userSliceReducer', 'filterSliceReducer', 
 'popularGiftsSliceReducer'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persisteConfig, reducers);

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: [thunk],
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;

En configureStore, en el campo middleware tengo un error de tipo que dice:
Type 'ThunkMiddleware<any, AnyAction, undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Middleware<...>'

De que manera podría solucionarlo?
Las librerías de mi package.json son:
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
"@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.3",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
"@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.8.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
"@types/node": "18.15.5",
"@types/react": "18.0.28",
"@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
"compressorjs": "^1.2.1",
"cookies-next": "^4.0.0",
"dayjs": "^1.11.8",
"eslint": "8.36.0",
"eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
"firebase": "^9.22.2",
"firebaseui": "^6.0.2",
"moment": "^2.30.1",
"next": "13.2.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.45.1",
"react-redux": "^8.1.1",
"redux": "^5.0.1",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
"typescript": "5.0.2",
"validator": "^13.11.0"

